# Tensorflow config "system picks an appropriate number"

Tags: tensorflow

Is there a documentation about the default values - the "appropriate numbers" of the session [config](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.proto), or I need to dig to the source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the specification is intentionally vague to accommodate for the device, OS, environment etc.

For example, when using eigen on CPU (which is what is currently used for various TensorFlow kernels), the default value of `intra_op_parallelism`  implies [the number of schedulable CPUs](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/local_device.cc#L35) in TensorFlow 1.2. The value here in turn may depend on things like the affinity mask on Linux (see [port.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/core/platform/posix/port.cc#L54)).

Long story short, yeah, you have to dig through the source to get an answer for a specific version of TensorFlow. And it isn't documented in detail to accommodate changes in the future. Ideally, the default values would work in most cases and only very advanced usage would require manually setting these parameters.

Hope that helps.